# Attribute error when closing from file? - learn python the hard way ex17

Tags: python, python-3.x

The sub-goal for this was to narrow down the code on lines 9 & 10 into one line. I tried to open the from file and read it but for some reason at the last line it gives me this:

"line 23, in 
from_file.close()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'close'"

I dont particularly know what str is but im mostly just trying to close the file out. sorry for this being poorly written im still new here thank you for your time.

```
from os.path import exists

script, from_file, to_file = argv

print(f"Copying from {from_file} to {to_file}")

#I am attempting to shorten the code here
indata = open(from_file).read()

print(f"The input file is {len(indata)} bytes long")

print(f"Does the output file exist? {exists(to_file)}")
print("Ready, hit RETURN to continue, CTRL-C to abort.")
input()

out_file = open(to_file, 'w')
out_file.write(indata)

print("Alright, all done.")

out_file.close()
# This line is drawing the attribute error
from_file.close()
```

Comment: You don't need to call `from_file.close()` since it's not a file handle - delete the line. But you do need to close the file that you did an `open(from_file)` on.

Comment: So instead of from_file.close I should have written indata.close? I apologize for the silly question.

Comment: You lose the file pointer because you do `open().read()` with `indata = open(from_file).read()`, so you can't close it (CPython will close it for you, but this isn't behavior to relay on). Don't condense it to one line for the sake of shortening for shortening's sake, especially if you're learning Python and aren't familiar with all the behaviors yet. I also imagine that soon enough, if you keep going with the resources you're using, you'll learn about `with` statements and context managers which will auto-close the file for you.

Answer (score 0):

`from_file` is referring to the path of the file. This is a `str` type in python. To close a file, you need to store the output of the `open()` call. Here, you never store the output of the `open()` call on line 8. Instead, you immediately call `.read()` on it and store the value of that to the variable `indata`. You can replace line 8 with these lines:

```
opened_from_file = open(from_file)
indata = opened_from_file.read()
```

Then, do close your file, replace line 23 with this:

```
opened_from_file.close()
```

Furthermore, its considered best practice to use context managers instead of manually opening/closing files because they will always close your file (currently, your file remains in memory if there is an error in your program). Read up on why its you should use context managers for file i/o here: https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html